# CUDA performance penalty when running in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, cuda, gpu

I've noticed a big performance hit when I run my CUDA application in Windows 7 (versus Linux).   I think I may know where the slowdown occurs:  For whatever reason, the Windows Nvidia driver (version 331.65) does not immediately dispatch a CUDA kernel when invoked via the runtime API. 
To illustrate the problem I profiled the mergeSort application (from the examples that ship with CUDA 5.5).

Consider first the kernel launch time when running in Linux:

[image: linux_launch]

Next, consider the launch time when running in Windows:

[image: windows_launch]

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349436/performance-penalty-when-invoking-a-cuda-kernel) suggests the problem might have something to do with the windows driver batching the kernel launches.  Is there anyway I can disable this batching?

I am running with a GTX 690 GPU, Windows 7, and version 331.65 of the Nvidia driver.

Comment: Usually, the first time launching the kernel in Windows may cost more time than second/third... time launching it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [fair amount of overhead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569747(v=vs.85).aspx) in sending GPU hardware commands through the WDDM stack.

As you've discovered, this means that under WDDM (only) GPU commands can get "batched" to amortize this overhead.  The batching process may (probably will) introduce some latency, which can be variable, depending on what else is going on.

The best solution under windows is to switch the operating mode of the GPU from WDDM to TCC, which can be done via the `nvidia-smi` command, but it is only supported on Tesla GPUs and certain members of the Quadro family of GPUs -- i.e. not GeForce.  (It also has the side effect of preventing the device from being used as a windows accelerated display adapter, which might be relevant for a Quadro device or a few specific older Fermi Tesla GPUs.)

AFAIK there is no officially documented method to circumvent or affect the WDDM batching process in the driver, but unofficially I've heard , according to Greg@NV in [this link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/548639/is-wddm-causing-this-/) the command to issue after the cuda kernel call is `cudaEventQuery(0);` which may/should cause the WDDM batch queue to "flush" to the GPU.

As Greg points out, extensive use of this mechanism will wipe out the amortization benefit, and may do more harm than good.

**EDIT:** moving forward to 2016, a newer recommendation for a "low-impact" flush of the WDDM command queue would be `cudaStreamQuery(stream);`

**EDIT2:** Using recent drivers on windows, you should be able to place Titan family GPUs in TCC mode, assuming you have some other GPU set up for primary display.  The `nvidia-smi` tool will allow you to switch modes (using `nvidia-smi --help` for more info).

Additional info about the TCC driver model can be found in the [windows install guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#driver-model), including that it may reduce the latency of kernel launches.

The statement about TCC support is a general one.  Not all Quadro GPUs are supported.  The final determinant of support for TCC (or not) on a particular GPU is the `nvidia-smi` tool.  Nothing here should be construed as a guarantee of support for TCC on your particular GPU.

Comment: Gosh, I guess I should have bought a Tesla seeing as I only want to use the GPU for CUDA processing (and not graphics).  I only got the GTX 690 because it seemed like a better deal as far as the $/processing power ratio ...

Comment: If you're the adventurous type, it may be possible to work around NVIDIA's crippling of GeForce hardware in this area by flashing another BIOS onto your card (it's possible on Fermi hardware but I haven't checked for Kepler).

Comment: GTX690 is based on two GK104 GPUs, which AFAIK have no DP units "disabled".

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Oops... I thought the GTX680 and GTX690 used the GK110. Looks like it's currently the high end GTX7xx cards that use a full GK110 with disabled double precision units.

Comment: @rmccabe3701: For CUDA, I would have gone with the Titan over the GTX690 because the two cost about the same and the Titan has full double precision floating point performance. The GTX690 has very few DP units. Also, the Titan, being a CC 3.5 device, supports Dynamic Parallelism (launching a kernel from within a kernel). The GTX690 is a CC 3.0 device without that support.

Comment: What is the source of the "newer recommendation" to use `cudaStreamQuery(stream )`?  Calling that has an impact on concurrent streams, as mentioned [here](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf), that in our usage had caused performance to worsen overall.  Also, I've seen that calling it on one stream can sometimes cause async copies on other streams to fail to be executed.  Beware.

Answer (score 0):

Even it's been almost 3 years since the issue has been active, I still consider it necesssary to provide my findings.

I've been in the same situation: the same cuda programme elapsed for 5ms in Ubuntu cuda 8.0 while over 30ms in Windows 10 cuda 10.1. Both with GTX 1080Ti.
However, in Windows when I changed the compiler from VS Studio to cmd's nvcc compiler suddenly the programme was boosted to the same speed as the Linux one.

This suggests that maybe the problem comes from Visual Studio.

Comment: In that case, check the command line arguments that your VS Studio solution is passing to nvcc. No magic involved here...