# CUDA: Strange timing using asynchronous transfer and kernrels

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to write my first cuda application. It acquires data at regular intervals (every 2.1 ms) and as it comes it, sends it off to the GPU for processing using CUDA. I have a few kernels written that appear to work properly, however the visual profiler is providing me with strange timing results that I can't seem to get to the bottom of. Here is the output from visual profiler (I cut off the beginning of the time trace to the left, as well as the end of my kernel executions to the right)

[Visual Profiler Weirdness #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lILk.png)

Each of those bursts in the "Runtime API" line are the API calls every time new data arrives, and the timing is what I expect. Each burst asynchronously transfers data and launches kernels into 1 of the 25 streams.

Why might the transfers and kernels start so long after the initial data transfer call? And why might they occur in bursts like that? That last burst doesn't actually finish for a while after the time shown. Oddly removing the kernels and just doing the data transfers makes everything happen quickly in succession, but long after the transfers were called. if it were a problem with my kernels, I would have expected each transfer to happen immediately following the API calls.

[Visual Profiler Weirdness #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvZwd.png)

I have seen another post with a similar issue but the fixes didn't change anything (I already moved my display onto my integrated mobo graphics, and I am not compiling with debug information).

Could the card be doing other things I'm unaware of? It is a GTX660. Could windows still be using it for display even though I have no monitor connected?

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: It could be WDDM batching.  It's impossible to tell with out having the code and running experiments.

Comment: What kind of experiments would you suggest? Should I get to work on a minimum working example?

Comment: To rule out WDDM batching, the best experiment is to run on a Linux system without X running, and profile there.   There's discussion on WDDM batching here on the CUDA tag.  You might try searching for it.  Such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944429/cuda-performance-penalty-when-running-in-windows)

Comment: Well that certainly sounds like what's happening. I can't really try it on a linux machine, but based on a link within your link, I think I see the same thing happening [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/548639/is-wddm-causing-this-/)

Comment: Fairly confident you're correct. Moving everything into the default stream lead to every kernel invocation waiting until the next synchronous memcpy was called. Placing a short synchronous memcpy after each group of kernel calls dispatches everything and everything works.