# cuda kernel execution delayed by cpu code

Tags: c++, cuda

I cannot get my head around the following admittedly very simple code, which is a boiled down version of a more complicated project where I spent many hours on by now.
This code as is will run on my system in about 2000 milliseconds. But when I enable the line to put cpu into sleep for 500 ms, the program alltogether will run that time longer, making it about 2500 ms.

I cannot understand how that fits into the statement that *cuda kernels execute asynchronously with respect to the host*?

Running cuda 11.1 on Vistual Studio 2019

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <thread>

__global__ void kernel(double* val, int siz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) val[i] = sqrt(val[i]); //calculate square root for every value in array
}

int main() {
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    const int siz = 1'000'000; //array length
    double* val = new double[siz];
    std::iota(val, val + siz, 0.0); //fill array with 0, 1, 2,...
    double* d_val;

    cudaMalloc(&d_val, sizeof(double) * siz);
    cudaMemcpy(d_val, val, sizeof(double) * siz, cudaMemcpyDefault);
    kernel <<<1, 1 >>> (d_val, siz); //start kernel
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500)); //---- putting cpu to sleep also delays kernel execution?
    cudaError_t err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "status: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
    std::cout << "duration: " << ms.count() << std::endl;

    delete[] val;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot understand how that fits into the statement that cuda kernels execute asynchronously with respect to the host?

You're experiencing WDDM Command Batching as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944429/cuda-performance-penalty-when-running-in-windows/19944714#19944714).

In a nutshell, on windows, when in the WDDM driver model, GPU commands (e.g. anything from the cuda runtime  API, plus kernel launches) will get sent to a command queue.  Every so often, according to an unpublished heuristic, and with no explicit user-controls provided, the command queue will be "flushed" i.e. sent to the GPU, at which time (if not currently busy) the GPU will begin processing those commands.

So, on a WDDM setup, the dispatch of kernels to the command queue is non-blocking (control is returned to the CPU thread immediately).  The dispatch of work from the command queue to the GPU follows some other heuristic.  (The kernel *execution* is asynchronous to the host thread, **in any event**)

You have at least a few options if this is a problem:

1. On windows, switch to a GPU that is in the TCC driver model.
2. On windows, attempt to use one of the "hacks" described in the linked answer.
3. Switch to linux

Comment: OK, based on the linked article I see that a `cudaStreamQuery(0);` directly after the kernel launch will do the trick here. Have to see how this works out in my real project. Thanks a lot for that hint. Man this is dumb...